# Empty Node Values When Transforming One Xml Document To Another using XSLT Templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform certain node values e.g to lowercase before importing XML Documents from the bank. Currently the output results in all values being removed from the original nodes except for the nodes I am actually transforming. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:iso20022="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="iso20022">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template match="iso20022:Document">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="iso20022:RvslInd">
    <RvslInd>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $uppercase, $lowercase)" />
    </RvslInd>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is an abbreviated example extract of the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BkToCstmrStmtV02 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
   <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId />
      <CreDtTm />
      <MsgRcpt>
         <Nm />
         <PstlAdr>
            <AdrTp />
            <StrtNm />
            <BldgNb />
            <PstCd />
            <TwnNm />
            <CtrySubDvsn />
            <Ctry />
            <AdrLine />
         </PstlAdr>
      </MsgRcpt>
      <AddtlInf />
   </GrpHdr>
   <Stmt>
      <Id />
      <ElctrncSeqNb />
      <CreDtTm />
      <FrToDt>
         <FrDtTm />
         <ToDtTm />
      </FrToDt>
      <RptgSrc>
         <Cd />
      </RptgSrc>
      <Acct>
         <Id>
            <Othr>
               <Id />
               <SchmeNm>
                  <Prtry />
               </SchmeNm>
            </Othr>
         </Id>
         <Ccy />
         <Nm />
         <Svcr>
            <FinInstnId>
               <ClrSysMmbId>
                  <ClrSysId>
                     <Prtry />
                  </ClrSysId>
                  <MmbId />
               </ClrSysMmbId>
               <Nm />
            </FinInstnId>
         </Svcr>
      </Acct>
      <Bal>
         <Tp>
            <CdOrPrtry>
               <Cd />
            </CdOrPrtry>
         </Tp>
         <Amt />
         <CdtDbtInd />
         <Dt>
            <Dt />
         </Dt>
      </Bal>
      <Bal>
         <Tp>
            <CdOrPrtry>
               <Cd />
            </CdOrPrtry>
         </Tp>
         <Amt />
         <CdtDbtInd />
         <Dt>
            <Dt />
         </Dt>
      </Bal>
      <Bal>
         <Tp>
            <CdOrPrtry>
               <Cd />
            </CdOrPrtry>
         </Tp>
         <Amt />
         <CdtDbtInd />
         <Dt>
            <Dt />
         </Dt>
      </Bal>
      <Bal>
         <Tp>
            <CdOrPrtry>
               <Cd />
            </CdOrPrtry>
         </Tp>
         <Amt />
         <CdtDbtInd />
         <Dt>
            <Dt />
         </Dt>
      </Bal>
      <TxsSummry>
         <TtlNtries>
            <NbOfNtries />
            <Sum />
            <TtlNetNtryAmt />
            <CdtDbtInd />
         </TtlNtries>
         <TtlCdtNtries>
            <NbOfNtries />
            <Sum />
         </TtlCdtNtries>
         <TtlDbtNtries>
            <NbOfNtries />
            <Sum />
         </TtlDbtNtries>
      </TxsSummry>
      <Ntry>
         <Amt />
         <CdtDbtInd />
         <RvslInd xmlns="">false</RvslInd>
         <Sts />
         <BookgDt>
            <Dt />
         </BookgDt>
         <ValDt>
            <Dt />
         </ValDt>
         <BkTxCd>
            <Prtry>
               <Cd />
               <Issr />
            </Prtry>
         </BkTxCd>
         <NtryDtls>
            <TxDtls>
               <Refs>
                  <EndToEndId />
               </Refs>
            </TxDtls>
         </NtryDtls>
         <AddtlNtryInf />
      </Ntry>
   </Stmt>
</BkToCstmrStmtV02>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (no input being provided) that you want to change this :

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The former copies only elements. The latter copies everything - including text() nodes.

Comment: Perfect, that did exactly what I needed. Thanks!